# How to simplify or wrap exceptions when rewriting synchronous code to use TPL

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

Given an implementation as follows:

```
public class SomeServiceWrapper
{
    public string GetSomeString()
    {
        try
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new ServiceWrapperException("Some Context", e);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            throw new ServiceWrapperException("Some Context", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The intention of the above is to enable the consumer of `GetSomeString` to only need to catch `ServiceWrapperException`.

Consider the following approach to extending this with a similar async behaviour:

```
public Task<string> GetSomeStringAsync()
{
    Task<string>.Factory doSomething = ...
    return doSomething.ContinueWith(x => 
    {
        if (x.IsFaulted)
        {
             if (x.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count() > 1)
             {
                 throw new AggregateException(x.Exception);
             }

             var firstException = x.Exception.InnerExceptions[0];
             if (typeof(firstException) == typeof(IOException)
                 || typeof(firstException) == typeof(WebException))
             {
                 throw new ServiceWrapperException("Some Context", firstException);
             }
        }

        return x.Result;
    }
}
```

This synchronous approach to wrapping exceptions doesn't fit naturally with the asynchronous approach.

What could the author of `SomeServiceWrapper` do to simplify the exception handling code of any consumers so they only need to handle `TradeLoaderException` instead of both `IOException` and `WebException`?

Comment: Can you use C# 5 `async`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, limited to .NET 4.

Comment: So what you can use `C# 5 async` using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) pack still targeting to .Net 4.0

Comment: You can actually use `async` with .Net 4 (I think you need VS2012 or later tho). See http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Answer (score 2):

I made an extension method that pretty much does that. Usage:

```
public static Task<string> GetSomeStringAsync()
{
    var doSomething = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "bar");
    return doSomething.WrapExceptions(typeof(IOException), typeof(WebException));
}
```

1. You can just return the original task with the continuation.
2. I would suggest changing ServiceWrapperException to hold more than one exception like AggregateException and then change the first part.

The Method:

```
public static Task<TResult> WrapExceptions<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, params Type[] exceptionTypes)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (_.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) return _.Result;

        if (_.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(_.Exception);
        }

        var innerException = _.Exception.InnerExceptions[0];
        if (exceptionTypes.Contains(innerException.GetType()))
        {
            throw new ServiceWrapperException("Some Context", innerException);
        }

        throw _.Exception;
    });
}
```

Comment: IMHO the exception thrown in continuation task will be also wrapped in AgreggateException by TPL...

Comment: @MichalLevý That depends on what you do with the task returned from `GetSomeStringAsync`. For example, if you `await` it you'll get the first exception, in this case `ServiceWrapperException`.

Comment: And when you do get an `AgreggateException` it will contain a `ServiceWrapperException`